# react-apollo-hooks useMutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

why "addTodo" in the "handleAdd" method gives me "method expression is not of function type" ?

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import useAddTodo from "../../hooks/todos/useAddTodo";

    function Home() {
        const [value, setValue] = useState('');
        const addTodo = useAddTodo();

        const handleChange = e => {
            setValue(e.target.value)
        };
        const handleAdd = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const todo = {
                title: value,
                status: false,
            };
            addTodo({
                variables: todo,
            })
        };
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleAdd}>
                <input onChange={handleChange} value={value} type="text" placeholder="todo title"/>
                <input onClick={handleAdd} type="submit" value="add"/>
            </form>
        );
    }

    export default Home;
```

here is my hook

```
import {useMutation} from 'react-apollo-hooks'
import AddTodoMutation from "./graphql/mutations/AddTodoMutation";

function useAddTodo() {
    return useMutation(AddTodoMutation);
}

export default useAddTodo
```

and my mutation

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export const AddTodoMutation = gql`
    mutation AddTodoMutation($title: String! $status: Boolean!) {
        addTodo(title: $title status: $status) {
            _id
            title
            status
        }
    }
`

export default AddTodoMutation
```

Can you guys explain to me what seems to be the problem? i would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that `react-apollo` supports hooks as of version 3.0 and `react-apollo-hooks` has been deprecated as a result.

Comment: lol, I felt in that case too (not assigning an array). There should be a way to control these developer errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`useMutation`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#usemutation) returns an array (not a single value).

For example:

```
const [addTodo, { data }] = useMutation(ADD_TODO);
```

However, it appears you're returning and invoking the entire array value.

To continue using your custom hook the way it is, try updating it as follows:

```
import {useMutation} from 'react-apollo-hooks'
import AddTodoMutation from "./graphql/mutations/AddTodoMutation";

function useAddTodo() {
   // Destructure the addTodo mutation
   const [addTodo] = useMutation(AddTodoMutation);
   // Return the value to continue using it as is in the other files
   return addTodo;
}

export default useAddTodo
```